# python file copy gives larger file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I stumbled across something that is not a problem, but something rather puzzling. I am copying a xml file `myxml.xml` to `myxml_copy.xml` and the file size of the output file is bigger. I don't understand why this is so. Does this have anything to do with file encoding?

Anyway, the code I am using (although it is fairly trivial):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import sys

def parseXml():
    data = open(in_filename,'r').read()
    return data


try:
    in_filename = sys.argv[1]
    out_filename = sys.argv[2]

    out_file = open(out_filename,'w')
    out_file.write(parseXml())
    out_file.close()
except Exception,e:
    print "usage: python copy.py <in_file> <out_file>"
    print "Error",e
```

---

NOTE: I am **not** looking for a way to copy a file. I will be modifying the original xml file later (cutting and pasting different parts of it).

Comment: If you open the files in binary mode, you'll probably see no difference..

Comment: @Levon this is on windows7, python v2.7.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that the mode you open the file with needs to be `rb` and not just `r` and `wb` instead of `w`. (means - with binary mode)

When it's `rb` - strings like `\r\n` will stay this way, but when the mode is `r` - they will become `\n`.

In short - just change the lines:

```
data = open(in_filename,'r').read()
out_file = open(out_filename,'w')
```

to

```
data = open(in_filename,'rb').read()
out_file = open(out_filename,'wb')
```

Did that help?

Comment: thanks! this was indeed the problem :)
It also explains why a diff between the two files resulted in almost all of the file being shown :P

Comment: The source of the input file must be a different OS since when I do this with Win7 (with a file created under Windows) I am ok with read/write w/o binary mode. I.e., I get the same sizes.

Comment: @Levon I think the original file is generated on CentOS, or something similar (guess it depends on which server is generating the response)

Comment: @ArnabDatta ah .. ok, that explains it .. glad it got all worked out.